# WP8 XAML ScrollViewer staying at chosen position

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, scrollviewer

I have a TextBox inside a ScrollViewer, as shown below

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer1" Height="480" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,480,8,82" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="480" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBox Name="box1" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="32" IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I don't want VerticalAlignment="Bottom" as I want to scroll to a specific place in the TextBox and for it to stay there without automatically scrolling to the bottom again.

Thanks

Comment: If you set text wrapping on the `TextBox` to `Wrap` it should display the scroll bars inside the `TextBox`. There's no need to wrap it in a `ScrollViewer` - unless you have other controls in there as well.

Comment: ChrisF is correct, there's a scrollviewer already built into the TextBox default control template you should interact with instead. So for example `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` and setting the `Width` applied directly to the `TextBox` makes the second SV unnecessary.

Comment: i removed the scrollviewer code and added VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" to the textbox however it is not possible to scroll in the textbox although the textbox contains text that cannot be seen. the textbox is in a grid not a stackpanel

Comment: @ChrisF @ChrisW. @Alex It does seem like `TextBox` in WP8 does not have a `ScrollViewer` in it's `ControlTemplate` and hence the problem unlike it's siblings in desktop environments. You can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16872378/1834662 for a solution