# WPF TextBox getting cut off

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

For some strange reason my WPF textbox which is embedded in a scroll viewer get abruptly cut off like in the image below after I have added a lot of text to it. Is there some limit or something that is reached that I can make larger or something?

[image]

I do not receive any error messages.

Here is the relevant Xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button x:Name="Slice_Button" Content="Slice" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Slice_Button_Click" Height="87" Background="#FF0D5B1E"/>
        <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="232,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="87" Click="Button_Click_1" Background="#FFC70E0E"/>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="505" Margin="10,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436">
            <TextBox x:Name="OutBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Output will be displayed here" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="2"/>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
```

Here is the C# I use to add the text:

```
main.DispatchInvoke(() =>
            {
                main.OutBox.Text += newText;
                main.Scroller.ScrollToVerticalOffset(main.Scroller.ScrollableHeight);
                main.Scroller.UpdateLayout();
            });
```

Comment: dude, post the relevant XAML...

Comment: sorry I forgot but I have added it now

Comment: Remove the `Height` and `Width` from stuff. WPF doesn't need that.

Comment: All that does is make my textbox smaller, It still has exactly the same problem

Comment: Dude,remove the `ScrollViewer`, you don't need that.  `TextBox` has its own ScrollViewer inside.

Comment: There would be a limit to the size of the text box. Why do you want to show the fill text box after putting it into a ScrollViewer? Try checking it using the `CanContentScroll` property of the ScrollViewer, setting it to true.

Comment: I am sorry if this sounds stupid but how can I get the Textbox to scroll without a scrollviewer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Second Update:**

Ok so I decided to get the windows phone kit and try this out.

`TextBox` as the OP mentioned just wouldn't scroll. Hence I decided to look at it's default `ControlTemplate`

This is the stripped out `ControlTemplate` from vs2012 with windows phone 8 sdk for `TextBox`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
  <Grid Background="Transparent">
    <!--  VisualState Groups for abt 100 lines  -->
    <Border x:Name="MainBorder"
            Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
    <Border x:Name="ReadonlyBorder"
            Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"
            Background="Transparent"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <Border Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"
            Background="Transparent"
            BorderBrush="Transparent"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
      <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement"
                      Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      BorderThickness="0"
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

No `ScrollViewer` just a `ContentControl`. The following is from vs2012 for a desktop app `TextBox`

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Border x:Name="border"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                  Focusable="False"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
  </Border>
```

Also verified this with Snoop by copying the phone template to my desktop app and same behavior.

Not sure abt the reasoning for why it doesn't have a `ScrollViewer`, but adding one in the `ControlTemplate` sorts the issue out.

**Solution:**

Full `Style` for `TextBox` with `ScrollViewer` (Added within "App.xaml" -> `<Application.Resources></Application.Resources>`

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1"
       TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="FontFamily"
          Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" />
  <Setter Property="FontSize"
          Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" />
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="SelectionBackground"
          Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="SelectionForeground"
          Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
          Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}" />
  <Setter Property="Padding"
          Value="2" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="Transparent" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Border x:Name="MainBorder"
                  Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
          <Border x:Name="ReadonlyBorder"
                  Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"
                  Background="Transparent"
                  BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Visibility="Collapsed" />
          <Border Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"
                  Background="Transparent"
                  BorderBrush="Transparent"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <ScrollViewer>
              <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement"
                              Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}"
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                              BorderThickness="0"
                              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
            </ScrollViewer>
          </Border>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

usage:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
      Grid.Row="1"
      Margin="12,0,12,0">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button x:Name="Slice_Button"
            Margin="10 0"
            Background="#FF0D5B1E"
            Content="Slice" />
    <Button x:Name="CancelButton"
            Margin="10 0"
            Background="#FFC70E0E"
            Content="Cancel" />
  </StackPanel>
  <TextBox x:Name="OutBox"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Margin="10"
           IsReadOnly="True"
           Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}"
           Text="Output will be displayed here"
           TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</Grid>
```

Do note just wrapping the `TextBox` in a `ScrollViewer` scroll's the entire control than just the content within it which might not be very appealing from a UX POV

**Download Link to Sample Project With above fix: [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybzlw9dslf1gfjv/PhoneApp1.rar)**

Comment: Windows Phone WPF does not have a DockPanel

Comment: @Gerhman oh i'm soz abt that then. well if it has a grid maybe even with that...ill update my answer in a sec

Comment: @Gerhman switched the `DockPanel` to a `Grid` with 2 `RowDefinitions` to get the same behavior. Hope that works.

Comment: thanks for editing it, it is now accepted but it does not scroll at all, not automatically nor with physical input(dragging it)

Comment: @Gerhman Hey I've updated my answer again and also added a download link at the bottom you can get and try for yourself. We need to update the Style for `TextBox` to get a `ScrollViewer` since it does not seem to be there by default on WP8.

Comment: Thanks a lot for figuring out the style, it simplifies the ui quite a bit but I still have almost my original problem. I get about 1 line of more of text before it stops writing text anymore and makes the scroll area huge. You can test this yourself by running a method that writes a line of text every few seconds for a while.

Comment: I don't follow your last comment sorry. Not sure what you even mean. If i add `Loaded += async (sender, args) => { for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { await Task.Delay(1000); OutBox.Text += Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Environment.NewLine; } };` to the MainPage constructor I can see the `TextBox` getting populated just fine.

Comment: what happens is that after the textbox has reached a certain of lines then it simply stops displaying any further lines that I add. It will create a large blank space.

Comment: @Gerhman hmm I get what you mean now. Yeh I see that too It renders 75 lines after that it seems to just not render the content anymore. It does not add any wasted space, that's just the kinetic scrolling but seems like lines >= 76 just don't get rendered. I'd say report a bug on msdn forums tbh unless you get an answer in SO from someone working with WP8

Comment: thanks for your help, I thought it might be a bug because I think there is no way that a textbox can run out of memory after just 75 lines! Hopefully someone else can help, otherwise I'll report it when I get time to do so.